# How to Launch Lan Messenger in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Downloaded and Installed Lan Messeneger.

It's installs succesfully.But there is no way to launch the Lan Messenger.Will this works for ubuntu.Is it a right package for ubuntu 14.04.?

Downloaded [from](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One you download it you can install:

```
sudo dpkg -i lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb
```

Once installation is finished you can run the app directly from terminal using command:

```
lmc &
```

The app will run and you can see the app indicator in the top panel

[image]

right click on the icon opens the menu so you can do what you want.

[image]

Also,  open `prefrences` then you can choose to make it run when system startup

[image]

Comment: `user@user-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Downloads$ lmc &
[1] 3843
user@user-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Downloads$ This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" 
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
` This was my error.can it be fixed?

Comment: You should ask it as separate question to get help from others also

Comment: I have added it as the new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/638366/lan-messeneger-launch-error

Comment: maybe this is not error

Comment: re read again my answer, did you see the indicator on the top panel?

Comment: no i can't see that icon from my system

Comment: ok then let me search for your peoblem

Answer (score 1):

I am able to install LAN Messenger with this package

https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/releases/download/v1.2.37/lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb

Which will install by software installer in ubuntu.