# How to install LAN Messenger in Ubuntu 16.04 and higher?

Tags: 16.04, lan

I want to install LAN Messenger in Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

I have referred following link but didn't get LAN Messenger install in my OS :
[How to Launch Lan Messenger in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638339/how-to-launch-lan-messenger-in-ubuntu-14-04?newreg=ec759fb4a34442babe7aec293e588500)

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

The Messenger was successfully installed but I am unable to open it. If I write command in terminal like `lmc &`, I am getting following error :

This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Also, I am not able to find LAN in my ubuntu.. as that link describes

Comment: Instructions and installation file are exactly the same for 16.04. What was the problem? Please [edit] and describe what happened, otherwise I'm afraid this question will be pure and simply ignored.

Comment: Please review my edited question

Comment: Try installing *libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0* -> `sudo apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`. If it works I can then make it into an answer and elaborate.

Comment: I have installed suggested plugins successfully, but still I am getting same error as I have describe in my edit.

Comment: Oh well, it seemed promising. Apparently the software itself needs a serious update so it no longer depends on deprecated libraries.

Comment: Yes, I guess so.. Please keep me updated here, if you will get any update or solution. Thank you so much for your suggestions

Comment: @MichaelBay, Is there any update for me regarding this?. Please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Instructions for installing LAN Messenger--a serverless text chat application--on Ubuntu/Mint 18.x.

Notes: If anyone would like to install this app on a 19.x O/S release, note that the procedure is somewhat different and it requires a bit of "hacking". I'll update this post with that procedure when I'm able... The LAN Messenger software has only been built for install on 64-bit Linux. If you require a 32-bit version, you'll need to build the app from the source code which is available at the web address shown below... Be aware that I've only tested the app's basic features, i.e. chatting and sending files between two computers and these functions appear to work quite well.

For what it's worth, here's a review of LAN Messenger from 2013:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/instant-message-anyone-on-your-home-network-with-lan-messenger/

As the first step in the process, boot into a *live* instance of the chosen Ubuntu/Mint 18.x distro. In my case, I had a live USB copy of Linux Mint 18.1 to work with. I recommend this step be done because it allows you to investigate LAN Messenger without altering anything in your computer's installed O/S.

Having booted into the live session, download the LAN Messenger .deb file from the app's website (https://lanmessenger.github.io/) and install it using GDebi by right-clicking on the .deb file and choosing "Open with GDebi Package Installer".

Once installed, try to run the app ("lmc") in the terminal. You'll likely get the following error:

> mint@mint ~ $ lmc /usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory
>   mint@mint ~ $

If so, then from the terminal update the package cache and then install the libqt5multimedia5 package:

```
​sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5
```

Again, try running the app in the terminal. If there are no fatal errors reported and the software's icon now exists in the system tray, left-click on it to access its menu options. Before continuing you may want to first "exit" the app in the system tray and confirm that it can be restarted from the system menu.

If everything works as expected, you can repeat the above process on a second computer on your home network (booting from a second live USB or DVD) and test the communication between both systems. When you first run the app on the second computer, you should be greeted with a notification message saying that the user on the first computer is available for chat...

Welcome to using LAN Messenger!